# Convert Custom Ubuntu 14.04 Build into Distribution USB

Tags: custom-installer

The idea is to give friends and acquaintances, who can't afford to replace their PCs, an alternative based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with most of the configuration processes already sorted out, therefore I need a custom build.

Using the standard ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit as a virtual machine under VMware Fusion on a Mac.  I have now customised this build to include a collection of apps and settings suitable for novice users.

What I'd like to do is to generate a USB stick and/or a DVD that can be used to trial (live boot) and install a copy of this custom build on old PCs to replace defunct versions of Windows (either obsolete, e.g. Win XP or simply damaged beyond repair, e.g heavily infected Win Vista)!

I've followed various articles both here and elsewhere but seem to keep going backwards – I want to do Z, fine but first do Y; I want to do Y, fine but first do X; etc.  I seem to be installing all sorts of utilities but end up getting further away from a solution!

Please can someone guide me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you want to do,

If you want a custom live-cd ("for trial purposes") then you are going about this the wrong way, a live cd is not merely a packaged VM image, ubuntu has an [extensively documented article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) on creating a customized live cd image.

If you want to create a custom installation-cd then you are also going about this the wrong way, an installation requires that the right arch-specific packages get installed for your users (so if you have a radeon card and they have an nvidia card, your image will not work them), this means configuring all the packages you want and the configuration options you want in a distributable manner. Luckily ubuntu *also* has an [extensively documented article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) in creating customized install cd's

If you want to be able to install a VM image to a drive, as in burn it directly, there are several options. Non of which are trivial, and none of which are very distributable. VM images are create for distributing AS vm images, and converting between different types of virtualized environments is also doable (So VMWare to VirtualBox, VMWare to AWS-AMI, VMWare to LXC container, are all doable). However there is no straightforward way of burning an disk image to a physical drive and running it on physical hardware without there being a big issue.